# Cross Compiling for a Rockchip SoC

Tags: arm, embedded-linux, cross-compiling, rockchip

I'm trying to cross compile a 'hello world' program for an **RK3128** SoC that I **believe** is running linux. The program should power the device off by running the `poweroff -f` command.

I have confirmed that the `poweroff -f` command when run from a bash script will turn off the device. Now I would like to do this in a C program.

```c
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        system("poweroff -f");
        return 0;
    }
```

I compiled this program for my AMD machine and it worked however, when I changed the compiler settings to target the **RK3128** ARM-based SoC, this program did not work.

I used the command below to cross compile my poweroff script for the **RK3128**:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --sysroot=[path to dumped filesystem from RK3128] -isysroot / main.c -o program -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -fPIC -march=armv7-a -v
```

What settings and or compiler can I use to do this successfully?

**NOTE**: The **RK3128** is located on a mini console featured in a [modding article](https://trustedsec.com/blog/hacking-the-my-arcade-contra-pocket-player-part-i). I do not have terminal access or serial access so my only means of debugging is seeing the screen power off.

---

If needed here's the output of `readelf -A game` where **game** is a functioning program stored on the **RK3128**

`readelf -A game`

```
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "Cortex-A7"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv4
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_rounding: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
  Tag_MPextension_use: Allowed
  Tag_DIV_use: Allowed in v7-A with integer division extension
  Tag_Virtualization_use: TrustZone and Virtualization Extensions
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run this program on the RK3128?  What output does it give and what is its exit status?  A typical hello world program will actually print something using `printf`.  I recommend getting that to work first before trying to shut off the computer.  You can use `strace` to help debug what your program is doing.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a console program in the NAND dump of the system. I can make it run a bash script, however there is no console to accompany the bash script. 

Since this is a linux arcade console, whenever the player presses the "START" button a bash script is run on the device to load the game. I have modified this bash script to run my own bash scripts which is how I am trying to run my c program.

Comment: "*RK3128 ... I believe is running linux*" - Since you claim to have the "*dumped filesystem from RK3128*", why can't you be certain?  "*I do not have terminal access or serial access*" - In Fig 3 of that article, I see an unpopulated 3-pin header near the Winbond NAND chip. That could be a header for a TTL serial port. If you're going to hack into a board, a serial console should be one of the first things to look for.

Comment: I believe it's Linux because when I ran binwalk on the dump I saw two Android boot images, a Linux Kernel, and a squashfs filesystem. I am not very familiar with kernels and boot images which is was why I think there may be a chance it is running Android. Any clarification on this or resources I can use to determine the OS would be really helpful.

Thanks for the tip with the TTL, I take a look at it once I get a backup board.

Comment: Why do you need "*a backup board*" to find a ground pin and then a TxD pin (using an oscilloscope or voltmeter)? BTW I wouldn't put too much trust in a "*modding article*" if it doesn't try to find a serial console or inspect/probe the function of that 3-pin header.

Comment: I'm worried about damaging the board and or case when opening it (I haven't had to open the case yet because I can instead flash the chip through the USB port). The creator of the article did mention in a separate post that they were able to compile programs for the device however they did not specify how they did so.

Comment: Why do you think the program exists in that firmware (Linux/Android image)? The `poweroff` is a part of traditional Linux distros, Android is not Linux, it only uses the Linux kernel.

Comment: I did a quick search to check how to differentiate the two which lead me to a post (I can't find the post) that stated to search for a specific file. My dump did not have that file so I concluded that the OS was probably Linux. Now, after reading the serial data from bootup I came across multiple lines mentioning an Android bootloader and loading an Android image. Does this mean the OS is instead Android? Also, I tried adding an echo script to print to serial however, nothing happened. It looks like only the bootup process can print to serial.